# Looking for title of a film about limbs being removed randomly

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror, episode-identification

I can't remember what the film was called.

Pertinent details that I remember:

- Subjects trade body parts/limbs chance at substance they need to live.
- Parts are turned into vials
- 10+ years ago
- Seen on Syfi or similar

There was also a scene with a room with a group of beggar like figures getting their limbs and organs taken by playing a sort of "Wheel of Fortune" game while there was a diminutive main character was not affected.
One guy gets his leg removed and screams in this sort of cheesy moaning. As I recall it was the type of horror that was self deprecating and humorous, lighthearted yet vulgar.

Edit: it's quite interesting what I recalled correctly and did not.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Great start. Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and see if you can edit in any more details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one of the early episodes of *Lexx*, titled "Eating Pattern"  -- the big bad guy was played by Rutger Hauer.  This was one of the two-hour movie productions, before *Lexx* changed to a one hour television series. It is available to view on YouTube, or was recently.

As noted, the wheel (strongly resembling the one in *Beyond Thunder Dome*) was spun, and the "contestant" might receive some of the glowing green fluid, or might have a body part removed and "cooked" into more of the fluid.  All of the denizens of this particular world (which was covered with junk and trash, despite having a broadcast billboard) were infested with a kind of worm that fed on the fluid, then eventually went to rejoin the parent worm, taking their person with them.